# Youtube Search Videos by ViewCount

Tags: php, laravel-4, youtube, youtube-api

I am looking for a way to query the YouTube API v3 with an Keyword and ViewCount:

**Like:** Give me all Videos with keyword "Stackoverflow" and more than 100 Views.

I know i can Order by ViewCount and could iterate over the results to plop out all Videos with lower views, but i hope there is an query param for this?

If someone knows an good example, or is able to find the Part in the Youtube-Api-V3 documentation.. In v2 it was possible with some kind XML Query:

```
entry[yt:statistics/@viewCount > 100]
```

Comment: V3 does not have a parameter allowing you to search by viewcount ... you'll have to do the ordering by viewcount, and then just filter on your end.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, so i have to hack some more code :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous API (2.0) had a query that allowed for searching by keyword and view count, but that was deprecated in 3.0.

As it stands now, you can search by keyword, and then get a result array of the 50 most viewed videos that match the keyword.  Once you have the result array, you can filter that by view count.

If you are looking to remove videos with a lower than normal view count, say 500 or less, you're likely not going to run into an issue where your result array has any videos with that few views.